# Java Jackson dynamically ignore specific properties of Exception class

Tags: java, exception, jackson

To log exceptions, I am serializing the exceptions using jackson and write them with a pretty printer to logging output. This works fine so far, my exceptions gets serialized and written with all of its properties.

Now i want to exclude some specific fields of the exception for the serialization depending on the log severity, e.g. ignore stacktrace in serialization for warning messages. How can I exclude fields of classes of the java standard library (Exception), where I cannot set jsonIgnore? How to set dynamically the to-be-serialized attributes of objects of classes like Exception?

Comment: You could take a look at JsonView

Comment: Just checked JsonView. The principle of this views are exactly what I am looking for. It seems I have to annotate the properties and its existance in each view. This would solve the problem for my own classes, but how can I annotate properties of library classes (like Exception)?

Comment: Pfuh. No idea, how you would do that.

Comment: to annotate properties of library classes use mixin